# Find exact cell-values in column1 and join values of column2 into new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv ('input.csv')
df.head()
df['visibility'] = np.where(df['sku']== df['parent-sku'], 'visible', 'search') #add column if same sku in parent-sku
  
combo4 = df.groupby(['parent-sku'])['sku'].apply(', '.join)
data = print(combo4)
df['grouped items'] = np.where(df['sku']== df['parent-sku'], data, '') #format(combo2)


df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

So, my goal is to go over all CSV file,
Check in column "PARENT-SKU" for repeating value in row, (4 items are same for exaple);
take values from SKU column (each is unique) next to it;
Merge with comma and append to new GROUPED column - only to first repeating of PARENT-SKU or only the one that has "VISIBLE"

Can't wrap my head around it. Whats wrong with it?
Curent output on grouped items is NaN.

Example of data:

| Parent SKU | SKU | VISIBLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | VISIBLE |
| A | A2 | SEARCH |
| A | A3 | SEARCH |
| B | B1 | VISIBLE |
| B | B2 | SEARCH |

I get wery veird results, when tried with function, would love to see output:

| Parent SKU | SKU | VISIBLE | GROUPED ITEMS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | VISIBLE | A1,A2,A3 |
| A | A2 | SEARCH |  |
| A | A3 | SEARCH |  |
| B | B1 | VISIBLE | B1,B2 |
| B | B2 | SEARCH |  |

Thanks a lot! And a beer for you!

Comment: Per you comment, try my updated answer. I’m on my mobile so haven’t tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.groupby` and `join` the items in the group to a string. From there use `mask` to identify `duplicated()` rows, which you can change to `''`.

*Per your comment*, you can also exclude certain words using `replace`, but you have to use some regex to also replace the comma depending if at front or back, but you don't want to replace font and back comma. Otherwise, some items won't be separated by commas. This regex `(,)?` looks backwards for an optional comma:

```
srs = df.groupby('Parent SKU')['SKU'].transform(','.join)
df['GROUPED ITEMS'] = (srs.replace(['simple(,)?', '(,)?simple'], '', regex=True)
                          .mask(srs.duplicated(), ''))
df
```

OR If you want in list format, then you can use `str.split(',')`:

```
srs = df.groupby('Parent SKU')['SKU'].transform(','.join)
df['GROUPED ITEMS'] = (srs.replace(['simple(,)?', '(,)?simple'], '', regex=True)
                          .mask(srs.duplicated(), ''))
df

Out[1]: 
  Parent SKU     SKU  VISIBLE GROUPED ITEMS
0          A      A1  VISIBLE         A1,A3
1          A  simple   SEARCH              
2          A      A3   SEARCH              
3          B      B1  VISIBLE         B1,B2
4          B      B2   SEARCH
```

Comment: Wow, this was really great.
Maybe you have idea how to skip in GROUPED ITEMS if there is "simple" in Column3(product-type) - otherwise, if there is simple as product type, it add for it grouped item SKU...  dont understand much python

Comment: wow, python is so powerful! thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Heres one way of doing that.

```
my_dict = {}
my_list = []

for val in df['Parent SKU'].values:
    my_dict[val] = []

for val in df['SKU'].values:
    if val[0] in my_dict:
       my_dict[val[0]].append(val)
    
for val in df['SKU'].values:
    if val[1] == '1':
        my_list.append(my_dict[val[0]])
    else:
        my_list.append('')

df['GROUPED ITEMS'] = my_list
```

**Output:**

```
     parentSKU  SKU   visible        GROUPED ITEMS
0         A     A1      visible        [A1, A2, A3]
1         A     A2      search  
2         A     A3      search  
3         B     B1      visible        [B1, B2]
4         B     B2      search
```